# change argument inside method

Tags: c++, methods, arguments

is it posible to change argument inside method?

```
int NumSet::max()
{
    int i, temp=1;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if (_num[i]>temp) temp=_num[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I want to use same method, for array _num and for lets say _num2.
thanks!

Comment: What type are the two array-likes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, consider using [`std::max_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) instead, which is a standard-library algorithm for finding the largest element in a sequence.  It's generally a good idea to avoid code duplication by using standard library features, as rolling your own algorithms provides an excellent opportunity to introduce bugs, and using the standard library makes your code more expressive and easier to read (and therefore maintain).

If `_num` and `_num2` are arrays (`int[]`) then you could do:

```
// Consider replacing the magic number 5 with a symbolic constant or variable.
int result = *(std::max_element(_num, _num + 5));
```

If they are some kind of STL container (such as `std::vector<int>`), then:

```
int result = *(std::max_element(_num.begin(), _num.end()));
```

If you do want to roll your own, then all you need to do is pass in some kind of reference or pointer to the array, depending on what kind it is.  Let's assume that these member variables are vectors (`std::vector<int>`).  One such implementation could be:

```
int NumSet::max(std::vector<int> const & sequence)
{
    int i, temp=1;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if (sequence[i]>temp) temp=sequence[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

(This assumes that the vector has at least five elements.  I would not suggest using this code, as it is susceptible to an out-of-bounds condition.)

Comment: If you have C++11, you can generalize to `std::begin(_num)` and `std::end(_num)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use the same method for different arrays. You need to pass the array as an argument to your method:

```
int NumSet::max(int* num, size_t n)
{
    if(n == 0)    // if array is empty
        return 0; // or something different

    int i, temp= num[0];
    for (i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (num[i]>temp) temp = num[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Then just call it twice with a different arguments:

```
 int max1 = max(_num, size_of_num);
 int max2 = max(_num2, size_of_num2);
```

Comment: I think `_num` is a member variable. It is not clear what he is asking though.